# Erroneous results from TIMESTAMP query on MariaDB 10.1.31

Tags: mysql, mariadb, amazon-rds

I'm getting some erroneous results from a query involving TIMESTAMP on MariaDB 10.1.31 and I thought I'd ask for a sanity check before submitting a bug report with the developers.

### BACKGROUND

I'm Running MariaDB 10.1.31 as an AWS RDS Instance.

Table has the following definition:

```
create table eventData_82_1_141 (
    moveid     INT(11)       UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    timestamp  TIMESTAMP(3)  NOT NULL,
    duration   MEDIUMINT(8)  UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    direction  TINYINT(3)    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    lock       SMALLINT(5)   UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    unlock     SMALLINT(5)   UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    peak       DOUBLE        NOT NULL,
    rms        DOUBLE        NOT NULL,
    temp       VARCHAR(6)    DEFAULT NULL,
    proc       TINYINT(1)    UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY ( moveid )
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

### ISSUE

When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM -table- WHERE timestamp <= NOW(3) ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 500
```

I get the following results set:

```
+--------+-------------------------+
| moveid |        timestamp        |
+--------+-------------------------+
| 23     | 2019-01-11 13:00:04.000 |
| 22     | 2019-01-11 12:57:32.000 |
| 21     | 2019-01-11 12:54:45.000 |
+--------+-------------------------+
```

NOW - When I execute the following logically-equivalent query (for all intents and purposes):

```
SELECT * FROM -table- ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 500
```

I get the following result set:

```
+--------+-------------------------+
| moveid |        timestamp        |
+--------+-------------------------+
| 43     | 2019-01-17 02:00:16.000 |
| 42     | 2019-01-17 01:57:05.000 |
| 41     | 2019-01-17 01:54:34.000 |
+--------+-------------------------+
```

### Questions:

Can anyone see something I'm missing?

Has anyone else experienced similar issues?

Is it worth a bug report to both AWS and the developers of MariaDB?

---

*EDIT:*

*I'm running exactly the same code, with exactly the same schema on multiple AWS Aurora 5.6 (MySQL 5.6.10) RDS instances and DO NOT receive erroneous results - it's only the 2 MariaDB instances which have this issue.*

---

*EDIT #2: (From comment below)*

*The results are the same whether or not I include the optional parameter for fractional seconds*

Comment: What is `NOW(3)` supposed to mean?  Why not just use `NOW()`?  I am not sure that I can reproduce what you are seeing here.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html

Comment: The results are the same whether or not you include the optional argument for fractional seconds.

Comment: What was the value of `NOW(3)` when you ran it?  What is the value at the moment?  Does it agree with the 'real' time?

Comment: It does indeed - down to the millisecond.  Good thinking though, thank you!